# MySQL how to implement condition in virtual field definition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the PHP function below to calculate checksums for strings in PHP. The xor is required to produce the same value on 32 and 64 bit php platforms.

I would like to create a virtual field in MySQL select queries that will have the same value. 
SELECT ABS(CRC32(ui_data)) As checksum FROM user_data works but I don't know how to implement the if part in a SELECT statement to make it fully compatible to the PHP function.

10X

```
function checksum ($orig_id) {
    $crc= abs (crc32($orig_id));
    if( $crc & 0x80000000){
      $crc ^= 0xffffffff;
      $crc += 1;
     }
    return $crc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(@crc & 0x80000000, @crc ^ 0xffffffff, @crc + 1)
FROM (SELECT @crc := ABS(CRC32('your_value'))) v
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html